# Dropdown menu with R outputs using Shiny in R Markdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am totally new to Shiny, so first, apologize my inexperience.

I am writing a dynamic report using R Markdown, and I have several plots that deserve being shown dynamically.

Let's work with the `mtcars` dataset, and let's create 4 plots:

```
plot1 <- plot(mtcars$mpg)
plot2 <- plot(mtcars$cyl)
plot3 <- plot(mtcars$hp)
plot4 <- plot(mtcars$qsec)
```

So, how can I create a dropdown menu with these four plots being displayed accordingly?

Comment: do you want to display all of these columns or only one?

Comment: I would like to select in the dropdown menu one of the 4 plots, and display it either on the right side or below the dropdown menu.

Comment: In that case you have two options: Either `shiny` or a complete standalone html with plotly.

Comment: Yes. I'd like to do it using `shiny`. However, I've been trying codes without success. Bear in mind that this is an example. Other times I am requiring PCA outputs from different data, for instance. Any simple code to do it in `shiny`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean your example is the simplest shiny example I have ever seen on stackoverflow. I suggest you take a bit of time doing the tutorial, then you try building your own app and if you're stuck come back here :)

To learn shiny I recommend [Rstudio's tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/). After learning and forgetting everything again I advise you to use the [wonderful cheatsheet provided by Rstudio](https://shiny.rstudio.com/images/shiny-cheatsheet.pdf).

The `app.r` looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

### ui.r
ui <- fluidPage(selectInput('my_dropdown','Choose Column',colnames(mtcars)),
                plotOutput('my_plot')
)

  ### server.r
  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$my_plot <- renderPlot(
      plot(mtcars[,input$my_dropdown],ylab=input$my_dropdown,xlab='value')
    )
  }
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Just for the sake of completeness. This kind of graph could be created using `plotly` as well. The advantage is that you can use this in a standalone `html`. The disadvantage is that dropdowns with plotly are quite code-intensive. The tutorial for `plotly` is here: https://plot.ly/r/dropdowns/